# Datetimepicker slider

Tags: jquery, datepicker, slider

Is it to possible to get datetimepicker http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ with a range slider http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#range for time range ?

**EDIT**
@Boris Delormas. I need to select date. Then select time range in that date.

Comment: By time range you mean date range? Do you want the datetimepicker to be impacted by a start date and an end date pikcked from the slider?

Comment: The demo in  http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/  is jqueryui datepicker.Why don't you use the same one.

Comment: @tanducar It is one of solutions. But if you have for ex. option to choose date and while regulating time you can see some info for this time period.. example provided by your link is unuseful. Anyway thx. If nobody know how to do it or it is difficult I'll find another solution..

Comment: have you got the solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

It will work for single handler slider with datepicker. For me, it's working fine.

```
$(function() {
  var baseDate = new Date(2011, 1-1, 1);
  $('#datepicker').datepicker(); // Initialise datepicker
  $('#slider').slider({ // Initialise slider
        slide: function(event, ui) { // As it slides
              var date = new Date(baseDate.getTime()); // Calculate the new date
              date.setDate(date.getDate() + ui.value);
              $('#datepicker').datepicker('setDate', date); // And set into the datepicker
        }
  });
});
```